# Why do I have Chinese/Mandarin characters in my mode-line and e-shell out of the blue? How do I fix this?

Tags: eshell, mode-line, doom, unicode, icons

I have been using Emacs for a while. As you can see in my config file ([whole file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el)), there is a snippet to provide a Doom mode line:

```lisp
(use-package doom-modeline
  :init (doom-modeline-mode 1)
  :custom ((doom-modeline-height 15)))
```

Unexpectedly, I started Emacs and now I am seeing some Chinese characters (left side):

[image]

This also happens in e-shell:

[image]

I suppose this might be some Unicode problem. Also, I must highlight that I am not Chinese, I do not speak Mandarin. So, this is completely random in my system for me and I have never seen such a thing before.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73120/how-to-turn-off-special-character

Comment: Try running both `M-x all-the-icons-install-fonts` and `M-x nerd-icons-install-fonts`.

Comment: Sorry, I tried your approach but I am still seeing some chinese icons in eshell, for instance. I also restarted emacs after executing your commands.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried <kbd>M-x all-the-icons-install-fonts</kbd>?

- [all-the-icons broken #724](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/issues/724)
- [domtronn/all-the-icons.el](https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. And it did not work. I am new to macOS. I think I pressed some random keybinding, that opened a font or typography menu, and I accidentally clicked on something. Now, I do not know how to re-store the previous state.